# Having problems with an index error (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

So I am having some trouble with my code.

Essentially, I am creating an initial array (x0x1) of random coordinates (this is successful). Then, I want to generate a candidate coordinate vector (z) from 3 random choice coordinate vectors from my original coordinate array. I then compare f(z) with every pair of coordinates f(x0x1[i]) in my original array. If f(z) is lower, then I take it to a new array of coordinates. The cycle repeats until I find the value of z that minimizes my function.

The error I get is : index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1, and it seems to be happening in my calculateFunction method. Not sure why.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random


def calculateFunctionValue(x):
    
    return (x[0]-1)**2+5(x[1]-x[0]**2)**2


def x0x1Array(N, F, K):
    
    x0x1 = np.zeros((N-1, 1), dtype=float)
    x0 = np.zeros((N-1, 1), dtype=float)
    x1 = np.zeros((N-1, 1), dtype=float)
    
    
    for i in range(0, len(x0)):
        for j in range(0, len(x1)):
                x0[i] = np.random.uniform(-2,2)
                x1[j] = np.random.uniform(-2,2)
                
    x0x1 = np.array((x0,x1)).T
                
    generateCandidateVector(x0x1, N, F, K)
           
            
def generateCandidateVector(newPopulationArray, N, F, K):
    
    x0 = np.zeros((1,2))
    x1 = np.zeros((1,2))
    x2 = np.zeros((1,2))
    populationOneArray = np.zeros((N-1, 1))
    generation = 0
    
    while generation <= K:
        generation = generation + 1
        for i in range(0, N-1):
            x0 = np.random.choice(len(newPopulationArray), 1)
            x1 = np.random.choice(len(newPopulationArray), 1)
            x2 = np.random.choice(len(newPopulationArray), 1)
            vectorZ = x0 + F*(x1-x2)
            
            if(calculateFunctionValue(vectorZ) < calculateFunctionValue(newPopulationArray[i])):
                vectorZ = newPopulationArray[i]
                print(vectorZ)
                return generateCandidateVector(vectorZ)
            
            elif(calculateFunctionValue(vectorZ) > calculateFunctionValue(newPopulationArray[i])):
                vectorZ = populationOneArray[i]
                
               
    
def main():
   
    K = 50
    F = 0.8
    N=50
    x0x1Array(N, F, K)
   
    
main()
```

The error trace is the following:

```
   runfile('C:/Users/SPNMo/Documents/untitled5.py', wdir='C:/Users/SPNMo/Documents')
[0]
C:\Users\SPNMo\Documents\untitled5.py:17: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  return (x[0]-1)**2+5(x[1]-x[0]**2)**2
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\SPNMo\Documents\untitled5.py", line 74, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:\Users\SPNMo\Documents\untitled5.py", line 71, in main
    x0x1Array(N, F, K)

  File "C:\Users\SPNMo\Documents\untitled5.py", line 35, in x0x1Array
    generateCandidateVector(x0x1, N, F, K)

  File "C:\Users\SPNMo\Documents\untitled5.py", line 55, in generateCandidateVector
    if(calculateFunctionValue(vectorZ) < calculateFunctionValue(newPopulationArray[i])):

  File "C:\Users\SPNMo\Documents\untitled5.py", line 17, in calculateFunctionValue
    return (x[0]-1)**2+5(x[1]-x[0]**2)**2

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Comment: Paste the full error and traceback.

Comment: Based on the full error message identify exactly which line has the problem (no **seems** allowed :)  ).  Then check the shape of the variable indexed.

Comment: done. I have posted it above

Comment: So you need to examine `x`.  The error says that `x[1]` is wrong.  Look up the stack, the `newPopulationArray[i]` looks suspicious.  Is that really a size 2 array?

Comment: Seems X is unidimensional and have only one element which is X[0] therefore X[1] is indeed out of bound. Check out what X is (print, log) and follow the execution, the error will then be explicit.

Comment: The x is just a vector (x[0], x[1]).

Comment: Is it really?  Have you checked?  Or are you just assuming or hopeing?

Comment: `x0` through `x2` are arrays of one element because of `np.random.choice(len(newPopulationArray), 1)`. Thus, `vectorZ = x0 + F*(x1-x2)` is an array of one element as well, since `F` is a number. Thus, `calculateFunctionValue(vectorZ)` calls this function on an array of _one_ element, but it expects two

Comment: If it's true the error would not complain for X[1] do log your execution and show us the result. Just trying to help here. This error is very basic and bloody explicit. Not logging and assuming is not the right way to debug.

Comment: Also, `5(x[1]-x[0]**2)` in `calculateFunctionValue` isn't multiplication by 5

Comment: Maybe I am getting my elements all confused haha. Essentially x0x1 array is just

[a, b]
[c, d] etc. 

Then I take three of these to calculate Z. which is also in the form [z1, z2]

Comment: Could you add `print(X)` in the method `calculateFunctionValue` before return and post the result of this print before the error happen. I am sure this will point out where the misunderstanding resides.

Comment: It it indeed gives me a value for example of [22.2], which indeed is not two coordinates.  Not sure why its doing that

Answer (score 1):

These 2 lines in x0x1Array function do not generate arrays of the same shape.

```
 x0x1 = np.zeros((N-1, 1), dtype=float) // shape is (49, 1)
 x0x1 = np.array((x0,x1)).T // shape is (1, 49, 2)
```

You should revisit the second line to create that array in a proper way.

UPDATE: getting 3 pairs from the list:

```
x0_ind, x1_ind, x2_ind = np.random.choice(lennewPopulationArray), 3)
x0 = newPopulationArray[x0_ind]
x1 = newPopulationArray[x1_ind]
x2 = newPopulationArray[x2_ind]
```

Also, in the calculateFunctionValue function add multiplication sign after the 5 so python knows to multiply

Comment: x0x1 = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, size = (N,2))

I think this is correct? It gives me what I need it seems. But the error still remains.

Comment: That definitely explains why `x[1]` is out of bound.

Comment: @WeightliftingWithoutLimits any chance you will log X in your function to explicitly show what is going wrong with your code?

Comment: @WeightliftingWithoutLimits the selection of your x0, x1 and x2 also seems not correct. you want to select random 3 pairs from the x0x1 array right? the current code is just selecting 3 indexes, but not the pairs themselves

Comment: When i print x before the function , i get [22.5] so it seems i am not getting a coordinate vector being input the function which is why I am getting out of bounds. Not sure why however.

Comment: @ArtakKirakosyan that is correct. I need the the pairs themselves, but unsure how to do that

Comment: I updated the answer showing how to get the pairs instead of indexes.

Comment: Many thanks buddy! I will look at this. I will be back if I still have problems with this code.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, to avoid such confusions, use IDEs such as PyCharm or Visual Code. They do code analysis and help you understand what is wrong with your code. Also, try learning debugging, that is an amazing tool for such cases.

Comment: Just a question, that 3 in the code len(newPopulationArray), 3), this 3 is meaning we want 3 pairs?

Comment: yes. that function selects 3 numbers which are smaller than the first argument to that function. len(newPopulationArray).

Comment: @WeightliftingWithoutLimits you can also reward the time and energy spent by the community user by casting your vote or/and mark as answer.

Comment: How do I do this. WIll certainly case the votes

Comment: there are upvote and downvote buttons next to the answer. Below it there is a check mark which will mark this answer as correct answer.

Comment: I have an additional question, i dont think my for loop is working in my code because i dont think its looping from 0 to N-1. I need an i somewhere but not sure where

Comment: Its only giving me one iteration

Comment: your generation function is a recursive function and at some point it will give an error, because in if statement you just pass one argument to itself, but that function requires 4 arguments. You have to revisit your logic and make everything clear to make it work